# word for a person who has shared similar experiences?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I am writing a paper on teaching life writing texts, and I have a section that discusses the benefits to a reader who has gone through the same traumatic experiences as the author of the text. My heading for this section is currently:

> **Benefits for the Sympathetic Reader**

However, "sympathetic" isn't quite the right word, considering the fact that the reader does not necessarily have to have shared these experiences in order to sympathize with the writer. Ideas?

Comment: *Sympathetic* is certainly not the word in non-technical use, though I cannot suggest a good expression myself.

Comment: @Fum I think this is related to the question you found, but not exactly a duplicate because different (though similar) specific contexts are provided with each.

Comment: Does your paper cover a particular kind of traumatic experience? I doubt you will get a good answer unless you edit it to supply more detail or clarify the question. As it stands, I think the question is off-topic as too broad, or it's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

A good answer is in your question... you could say: **Benefits for those with** (or, *who have had*) **similar experiences.** If you want a term for people who have had comparable experiences which seem to create a pattern, you might say they have had ***"parallel lives"***.

Answer (score -1):

Could you do something along the lines of "fellow-sufferer"?